# Incorrect syntax on HttpRequest

Tags: python, django

I am doing the introduction to Django tutorial from here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/

Within it, I create this method in my project's `view.py`:

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)
```

I am calling that method from `urls.py`:

```
detail(request=<HttpRequest object>, question_id='34')
```

So I am following the steps in the tutorial exactly but I am getting this error:

```
    detail(request=<HttpRequest object>, question_id='34')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is that the case?

Comment: Put the urls.py file code in question

Comment: The tutorial really doesn't tell you to use that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
detail(request=<HttpRequest object>, question_id='34')
```

is an explanation of what's happening behind the scenes, not the syntax that you should use.

You should define the `detail` function as such:

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    # your view logic here
```

And then, when you'll try to reach the url that refers to the `detail` view, Django will automatically pass the `HttpRequest object` for you, together with the specified `question_id`.